# Does this PHP Session authentication method safety enough?

Tags: php, session, authentication

Is it safety enough to use such method?

```
// validation.php        
if ($login == $r['username'] && $pass == $r['password'])
{
$_SESSION['user'] = $login; 
}
```

And then on each secret page:

```
// protectedpage.php    
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
echo "Go be unlogged somewhere else!<br>";
exit;
}
```

Comment: The fact that you're doing `$pass == $r['password']` tells me no, it isn't. I would wager you're storing passwords in plain text, which is bad!!!!! As for the session checking, nothing wrong with doing a session check to make sure users are logged in.

Comment: I do $pass=crypt($_POST["password"],15); and compare crypted version of password. Is it ok?

Comment: Take a look at this, this is a great way to store salted / hashed passwords. https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm#phpsourcecode
Only two methods you would care about would be `create_hash` and `validate_password`